# localStorage assignment vs. setItem()

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

One of the [first results from a Google search](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) says that this syntax is to be used for localStorage:

```
localStorage.lastname="Smith";
```

MDN uses .setItem() and .getItem(), I suppose so that if the browser doesn't support localStorage, then you can add it using the [technique defined there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

But since my program is only running on iOS, I guess my question is:

Is it ok to use

```
localStorage.lastname="Smith";
```

instead of:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("lastname","Smith");
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't trust w3schools, especially when it comes to best practices...

Comment: If you're only concerned about one OS, why not simply test it on that OS. That would remove any doubt about the accuracy of third party sources.

Comment: I would follow the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#storage If the device doesn't support the spec, I would then use a polyfill to keep my code consistent with the spec.

Comment: If getItem and setItem work now, and are the standard - then I would stick with them. Whilst object syntax may work on iOs now, you cannot guarantee that will continue to be the case in the future - a standard is much more likely to enjoy continuing support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though both methods are valid JavaScript,

```
localStorage.lastName = "Smith";
```

assigning a value directly like above to a key can sometimes result in property conflicts.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("lastname","Smith");
```

On the other hand is a better practice to get into. MDN and most other resources recommend this method when working with Local-storage.